# Force a flush in Shiny Dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am using a shiny app to display some basic information, sales data etc. The data are retrieved from an SQL Server. As loading these Information takes 10-30 seconds, I want the user to see some basic information on the customer while the main part of data is still loading.

I use `observeEvent(input$button, {...})` to start data retrieval. After ~1 second the basic information are loaded and displayed via `renderText`. After this, SQL keeps loading other information. Problem: Basic information that are already rendered are not displayed in the app, not before all data are loaded.

How can i force the server to flush the rendered data to the ui?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. But I didn‘t spent much more time finding a solution as the project was cancelled.